# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function displayimage()

Tags: php, database, image

Im trying to get images that have been uploaded to my database and display them on another page of the website. The image goes into the database but doesn't display and this error message  keeps coming up:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function displayimage()
>   in C:\Xampp\htdocs\website2\profiletest.php:191 Stack trace: #0 {main}
>   thrown in C:\Xampp\htdocs\website2\profiletest.php on line 191

Im not to sure how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

**profiletest.php**

```
<?php
   if (isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
       if (getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])== FALSE)
       {
           echo "Please select an image.";
       }
       else
       {
           $image= addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
           $name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
           $image= file_get_contents($image);
           $image= base64_encode($image);
           saveimage($name, $image);
       }
   }
    displayimage();
   function saveimage($name, $image)
   {
        include 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
       $qry="INSERT into images (name, image) values ('$name', '$image')";
       $result=mysqli_query($conn, $qry);
       if ($result)
       {
           echo "<br/>Image Uploaded.";
       }
       else
       {
           echo "<br/>Image not uploaded";
       }
   }

?>
```

**exploretest.php**

```
<?php

          include 'includes/dbh.inc.php';

            function displayimage() {
           $qry="select * from images";
           $result=mysqli_query($conn, $qry);
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
           {
               echo '<img height="300" width="300" src="data:image;base64, '.$row[2].'">';
           }
           mysqli_close($conn);
       }
    ?>
```

Comment: this is a variable scope issue

Comment: does `profiletest.php` include `exploretest.php` at any point in execution?

Comment: No i dont think it does

Comment: how do i go about doing this